# Why does an aggregated calculated member yield the same result irrespective of the measures in the SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

When I create a calculated member using the `AGGREGATE` function why does the value in Axis 0 (where `MEASURE` is selected) stay the same, **irrespective** of whichever `MEASURE` is used.

**Definition of calculated member**

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].Year.x2010 AS
  AGGREGATE(
    [Date].Year.&[2010] * {[Client].[Client Number].&[000058]}
    , [Measures].[Claim As Of - Count]
  )
SELECT  
  {[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count], [Measures].[Incurred Amount % of Total As Of - Avg]} ON 0,
  {[Date].[Year].[x2010],[Date].[Year].[2010]}  ON 1
FROM [AW Cube]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

For the *regular* member the output changes with differnt measures, but for the calculated member, it doesn't.

Comment: You explicitly say in the definition of `[Date].Year.x2010` that the measure `Claim As Of - Count` is to be used. I would suggest to call `Aggregate` with only the first argument, i. e. `AGGREGATE([Date].Year.&[2010] * {[Client].[Client Number].&[000058]})`

Comment: @FrankPl the OP expression looks sort of strange? Is it not better practice to create some sort of member in `[Measures]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculated value x2010 does not depend on the 'current' Measures because it is explicitly saying to use [Claim As Of - Count]. As FrankPI suggested removing the Measures from the formula should solve the issue.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer as it solves the problem, but I am also interested in knowing how exactly this calculated member slices the measures axis and why the result is static, i.e. the inner working. How is the measures dimension sliced, etc. Thanks

Comment: A result cell is the value of the tuple (aka. coordinates in the cube).  The tuples containing the x2010 calc. member are computed using its formula which requests the cell ( ..., [Claim...]); you get the same value each time as the two tuples will reference the same Measures.

Comment: So you mean that since Measures dimension has already been used once(in the formula), it is not used again in the tuple? That makes sense.

Comment: Yes. The tuple specified has to be completed before evaluation: it must contain a member of each indexing dimension of the cube (the only way to locate the cell in the cube) : e.g. the slicer (WHERE) is possibly adding members to the specified tuple, the content of the axes, etc... Note that the default members of all the non-specified dimensions are used as well. In your case, the member of the [Measures] has been explicitly specified so no need to complete; the same [Measures] will be used each time this formula is being evaluated.